# Molecular solid HF

Tags: physical-chemistry

Considering a hypothetical one-dimensional molecular solid made up of HF molecules, is the distance between two subsequent HF molecules shorter or larger than the distance between each H-F bond?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be more of a chemistry question than a physics question.